# Blank white page after checkout also customer automatically logged out on OpenCart

Tags: php, callback, payment-gateway, checkout, opencart-3

guys I thought you might be able to help me.

From 7 days ago my site ran into a strange problem and everything was working normally until 8 days ago, I have changed nothing on my site.
(In a random time range like yesterday 1 PM to 5 PM and today from 1 AM until 9 AM) After successful payment when the customer comes back to my site, it loads a blank white page and it won't go to the success page.
Also, I find out after customers come back to my site he/she is no longer logged into his/her account (site automatically logged them out)
Also, it's worth mention that My site functions normally in some random hours of the day.

Here are the errors that I get:

---

```
error on saman payment gateway:
2020-08-15 13:46:55 - PHP Notice: Undefined index: payment_method in /home/site/domains/mysite.com/public_html/catalog/controller/extension/payment/saman.php on line 94

-line 94
public function callback() {
if ($this->session->data['payment_method']['code'] == 'saman') {
$this->load->language('extension/payment/saman');
_________________________________________________________________
error on mellat payment gateway:
2020-08-15 15:06:20 - PHP Notice: Undefined index: payment_method in /home/site/domains/mysite.com/public_html/catalog/controller/extension/payment/mellat.php on line 63

-line 63
public function callback() {
if ($this->session->data['payment_method']['code'] == 'mellat') {
$this->load->language('extension/payment/mellat');
```

I check with the cloud provider even change my cloud service to ArvanCloud but the problem still exists, Also I talk to all my payment gateway providers, some of them told me that it might be a timeout type of error (it take longer than expected to receive a verify so the callback fails) but I think it's related to the session since my customers get logged out the site after they get to the blank white page instead of checkout success. (I think it's because of they automatically log out that the callback can't get the session in error above)

Do you think that there might be a solution to my problem since it happens randomly and no errors can be found in the server error log?

I use OpenCart 3.0.2.0